# Listen for harware change events from the linux kernel or udev

Tags: c, linux, events, storage, udev

I need to run some code on storage device mounting and unmounting.
How can i listen for these events on linux?

- I was thinking on adding some [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rules to run some script (any know-how in this matter is appreciated).
- But I would much rather listen for events from the kernel in some netlink socket with my daemon (just like udev does) or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [libudev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/ch01.html) or the more convenient, glib based [gudev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/gudev/) to monitor udev events in C.

Answer (score 2):

You have to listen to the "[uevent](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/gudev/GUdevClient.html#GUdevClient-uevent)" signal. Attach a callback to this signal and wait for the notification.